# Python NameError: name is not defined but can't capture the error

Tags: python, nameerror

```
def strornum(a):
    try:
        return(a/1)
    except Exception:
        return("ERROR")
    
bob=strornum("W")
print(bob)
```

This gives me the correct error of "ERROR"

```
def strornum(a):
    try:
        return(a/1)
    except Exception:
        return("ERROR")
    
bob=strornum(W)
print(bob)
```

This is not handled and gives me  "NameError: name 'W' is not defined"
I need to capture this error

Any ideas?

Comment: There is no try/except around the use of `W`, just put one around `bob=strornum(W)` but this as no sense, because the variable is defined or not when you write the script, except if the variable is defined in an `if` block <<== in that case raise the error in the else. **Don't use NameError** to do code

Comment: Or explain really why you think you need to catch that

Comment: The error happens before you call the function. How could a `try` inside the function catch it?

Comment: `"W"` means the one-character string which has a `W` for its only character. `W` means the variable named `W`, which obviously, is not defined. It shouldn't be necessary to catch NameErrors, because you should already know what names are defined in your code when you code it.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi He knows that. He just wants his `try/except` to catch the error from the undefined variable.

Comment: I'll explain what I'm trying to do. I want to only accept a number from a function call e.g. no "w" and no w

Comment: @Mark then that's the question you should ask. https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/174780

Answer (score 0):

What you want is not possible.

When you call a function, all the arguments are evaluated *before* the code in the function is executed. Python doesn't wait until you refer to the parameter variable inside the function (there are some languages that do this, it's called "lazy evaluation").

So the error is raised in the calling code, before entering your `try/except` block, so it can't catch it there.

Answer (score 0):

Running the failing code gives the traceback message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 7, in <module>
    bob=strornum(W)
NameError: name 'W' is not defined
```

The error was raised when you tried to call the function, not in the function itself. `W` is not defined at the point of the call. The solution is to add another exception handler at that level.

```
def strornum(a):
    try:
        return(a/1)
    except Exception:
        return("ERROR")

try:
    bob=strornum(W)
    print(bob)
except Exception:
    print("Outer Error")
```

*obligatory warning*: Catching all exceptions is usually not a good idea because it can mask real problems with your code.